# Including a subfolder from an excluded folder in .gcloudignore

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to deploy a Node project with a Dockerfile to Google Cloud Run with the [`gcloud beta run deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy) command.

Long story short, I would like to copy my local `node_modules/my-module` after running `RUN npm install` in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY node_modules/my-module /app/node_modules/my-module/
```

(I only do this while in development, to avoid committing and pushing every change from `my-module` for testing).

Unfortunately, Docker cannot copy this directory since, apparently, `node_modules` is not uploaded to Cloud Build by default.

So I created this [`.gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) file to override the default:

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore

node_modules/
!node_modules/my-module/
```

I've tried a lot of other syntaxes but none allowed me to exclude `node_modules` while including `node_modules/my-module`.

However, I can include the whole `node_modules` directory by omitting it from the `.gcloudignore` file, but this obviously takes forever to upload.

Do you know how I could upload my local module to Cloud Build?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading [this Gist's comments](https://gist.github.com/cbandy/b58d32fe44dcbaa91f35e821efb72066#gistcomment-2870193), I realized you have to also include the parent directories, like so:

```
node_modules/**

!node_modules/
!node_modules/my-module/**
```

This will exclude all subfolders from `node_modules` except `my-module` and its content (the `**` is important, otherwise only the empty folder would be included).